# java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double Error when trying to return Map[(String, String),(Double, Double)] from RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to read a .txt file with `|` delimiters as an RDD  and trying return a `Map[(String, String),(Double, Double)]` , however I am running into CastException

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
```

input data looks like this

```
string1|string2|100.00|200.00
string1|string2|34.98|0.989
```

this is how i am reading the file as rdd and parsing it

```
val mydata = sc
  .textFile("file")
  .map(line => line.split("|"))
  .map(row =>
    ((row(0), row(1)),
     (row(2).asInstanceOf[Double], row(3).asInstanceOf[Double])))
  .collect
  .toMap
```

How can I fix this issue

expected o/p:

```
Map[(String, String),(Double, Double)] = Map((string1,string2) -> (100.0,200.0), (string1,string2) -> (34.98,0.989))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be on the safe side you can use `trim` function and you can use `collectAsMap`

```
val mydata = sc
  .textFile("file")
  .map(line => line.split("\\|"))
  .map(row =>
    ((row(0), row(1)),
      (row(2).trim.asInstanceOf[Double], row(3).trim.asInstanceOf[Double])))
  .collectAsMap()
```

And to be more safe you can use `Try/getOrElse`

```
val mydata = sc
  .textFile("file")
  .map(line => line.split("\\|"))
  .map(row =>
    ((row(0), row(1)),
      (Try(row(2).trim.asInstanceOf[Double]).getOrElse(0.0), Try(row(3).trim.asInstanceOf[Double]).getOrElse(0.0))))
  .collectAsMap()
```

Moreover you can use `toDouble` instead of `asInstanceOf[Double]`

```
val mydata = sc
  .textFile("file")
  .map(line => line.split("\\|"))
  .map(row =>
    ((row(0), row(1)), 
      (Try(row(2).trim.toDouble).getOrElse(0.0), Try(row(3).trim.toDouble).getOrElse(0.0)))
  )
  .collectAsMap().foreach(println)
```

Comment: this is splitting every word into character. `scala.collection.Map[(String, String),(Double, Double)] = Map((s,t) -> (0.0,0.0))`

Comment: You had to escape the pipe delimiter :)

Comment: @Sanjay see my latest update. you should use toDouble

Comment: well escaping the pipe got it working but its returing ( 0.0,0.0) for all .
`mydata.get("string1","string2")
res32: Option[(Double, Double)] = Some((0.0,0.0))`